# Tracing a PHP "out of memory" error

Tags: php, debugging, yii

I'm building an application with the Yii framework and am trying to determine the cause of an out of memory error.  Is it possible to get a stack trace?  I've tried doing something like...

```
function handleShutdown() {
    debug_print_backtrace();
    $error = error_get_last();
    $info = "[SHUTDOWN] file:".$error['file']." | ln:".$error['line']." | msg:".$error['message'] .PHP_EOL;
    echo $info;
}
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
```

But the debug_print_backtrace() doesn't show anything but

```
#0 handleShutdown()
[SHUTDOWN] file:C:\Users\bkuhl\htdocs\instaLabel\yii-1.1.12\base\CModule.php | ln:530 | msg:Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)
```

I've checked CModule.php and there's no line number 530 in that file.  It only goes to 518.

Comment: Cause of out of memory error: you are using too much memory. In most cases this means that you are grabbing a large database result set into memory piecemeal.

Comment: http://v1.srcnix.com/2010/02/10/7-tips-to-prevent-php-running-out-of-memory/

Comment: PHP >= 5.3.0, gc_enable() + gc_collect_cycles() also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, this was happening because I had infinite function recursion.  When I added the xDebug extension to PHP it threw an accurate error due to the function call limit.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your app with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). It should tell you which function is called how often and how much memory it eats.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind because of the fatal memory error it is difficult to debug simply because, well, you might not have enough memory left to run your debugger.

For example if I have 100 bytes left I won't be able to run much. So the results of your shutdown function will vary.

Now as for your line number that doesn't exist.. is it possible the file is running an eval(), pulling in another file or outputting something that may cause the erroneous line number? I would read that file and the calling files and see how it's ran. Sorry I can't help further, I'm not familiar with the Yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to find the backtrace from a Fatal Error using the shutdown function since this function is called from the PHP lifecycle, instead of some other piece of code. Thus, your stacktrace is correct - that's the stacktrace of the shutdown function, which is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to intercept **Out Of Memory** error like it was done in [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1fa763620542d5d76db033474a3a5d508177b505/src/Symfony/Component/ErrorHandler/ErrorHandler.php#LL617C21-L617C21).

Symfony reserves some memory(32k) for fatal errors handling and then release it in case of exception.

Unfortunately, still, there is no way to get correct stack trace via code but you can set breakpoint in xDebug on your handler specified in *register_shutdown_function* and see correct stack trace.